# The type xx cannot be used as type parameter

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I use the following in my program.cs for my ASP.NET Mvc web

```
var emailConfig = builder.Configuration
    .GetSection("Email")
    .Get<EmailConfig>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
```

The site run as it should but I get a warning in visual studio on AddSingleton line telling me

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning   CS8634  The type 'Common.Models.EmailConfig?' cannot be used as
> type parameter 'TService' in the generic type or method
> 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton(IServiceCollection,
> TService)'. Nullability of type argument 'Common.Models.EmailConfig?'
> doesn't match 'class'
> constraint.   WebbSite    D:\Test\1\WebbSite\Program.cs   62  Active "

I dont understand the problem, can someone explain and tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConfigurationBinder.Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration)) returns `T?` since .NET 7 (compare with .NET 6 [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration))) so if `T` is reference type it becomes a [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) (also see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)) so in nullable aware context static flow analysis that determines if a variable may be null before dereferencing produces the aforementioned warning. This warning can be removed by adding null check (or null-forgiving operator):

```cs
var emailConfig = builder.Configuration
    .GetSection("Email")
    .Get<EmailConfig>();
if(emailConfig == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Email configuration is missing");
}
builder.Services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);
```